# How to load page with include

Tags: php

I'm Trying to write a page in php that save code for php file, in that file I have to load diffrent pages by links

this is my page select function:

```
$page_to_see=$_GET['PageToSee'];
if (!isset($page_to_see))  
{
    $page_to_see="include 'pages/home.html';";
}
else
{
    $page_to_see="include 'pages/".$page_to_see.".html';";
}
```

the $_GET get the value from the link (www.mysite.com/myfile.php?PageToSee=home)

in the writing to file the code is:

```
$content="<table align='center'>";
$content.="<tr align='center'>";
$content.="<td align='center'>";
$content.="<?PHP include 'pages/header.php'; ?>";
$content.="</td></tr>";
$content.="<tr><td align='center'>";
$content.="<?PHP echo $page_to_see; ?>";
$content.="</td>";
$content.="</tr>";
$content.="</table>";
```

all i get on the preview is the header and nothing else

Can anyone help me I don't know what to do any more, i tried a few thing nothing helped :-(

Comment: $content="<table align='center'>"; ....etc this code in which file?

Comment: in other file that write html file, the $page_to_see function is included in the writing file but It only read the var $page_to_see when a user load the page that has been written

Answer (score 0):

First, in your PHP file, you must define an array of strings that specifies the pages you actually **can** include, to avoid includes injection.

Then, you have to test your `$_GET` variable to know if it corresponds to any entry in the array.

myFile.php :

```
$pages = array('home', 'page2', 'page3');
if(in_array($_GET['PageToSee'], $pages)) {
    include($_GET['PageToSee'].'php'); // Add correct extension of your file
}
```

Also, for your html, you must output a correct anchor :

```
echo '<a href="./myFile.php?PageToSee=home">Some Label</a>';
```

Comment: Thank's it didn't work at first but I took your idea and changed it a little and works fine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This line is strange :

```
$content.="<?PHP echo $page_to_see; ?>";
```

Maybe it should be a simple:

```
$content.= $page_to_see;
```

---

You don't need quotes in this:

```
$page_to_see="include 'pages/".$page_to_see.".html';";
```

Try to change it to:

```
$page_to_see= include 'pages/".$page_to_see.".html';
```

[See the example #5 in the php docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: I can't use simple $content.= $page_to_see; because then I get error Undefined variable: page_to_see, the var is read only in when I go to the new file that it builed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this but make sure that your $page_to_see is [absolute url](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/replace-relative-urls-with-absolute-urls-php/)

```
<?php
      $content="<table align='center'>";
      $content.="<tr align='center'>";
      $content.="<td align='center'>";
      $content.= file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/pages/header.php');
      $content.="</td></tr>";
      $content.="<tr><td align='center'>";
      $content.= file_get_contents($page_to_see);
      $content.="</td>";
      $content.="</tr>";
      $content.="</table>";
     echo $content;
 ?>
```

Comment: I can't use simple $content.= $page_to_see; because then I get error Undefined variable: page_to_see, the var is read only in when I go to the new file that it builed – Gil Josef just now edit